# Set Containment of Spaces in Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions, partial-differential-equations

Can anyone explain the Set-Theoretic Containment of Spaces (Function Spaces) used in Functional Analysis?
The Function Spaces I know of are the $L_p$ Spaces$, C_0$ , $ C_c$ , $C^\infty$ and their related ones, Sobolev spaces $W^{k,p}$ , and also BV spaces. Please add any other spaces you may know of. If possible please mention if any Space is dense in the other. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: $C_c$ is dense in $C_0$ and for regular measures $C_c$ is also dense in $L^p$.  I think Rudin‘s RCA contains proofs for that statements but this is not a complete answer, hence the comment.

Comment: Dunford and Schwartz discusss a lot of these standard spaces and their interrelationships.

Comment: Yeah thanks... I know the basics ones ..but confused with the Later ones ...so to make a complete list I added all the spaces.